# Menu interfering with my gridview control

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, gridview, z-index

I implemented gridviewscroll from http://gridviewscroll.aspcity.idv.tw/Demo.aspx#Freeze 
on my web application but the menu seems to hide behind the gridview like in the below picture:

[image]

the actual menu looks like this on other webforms:
[image]

My question is how do I send the gridview behind or how else can i work around this issue?

P.S. if you need any code to clarify things, ask me.

It works well on other GridViews, i tried increasing the z-index but it doesn't work.

```
nav ul ul {
    display: none;
}

    nav ul li:hover > ul {
        display: block;
    }
    nav ul {
    background: #FFF4D5; 
    background: linear-gradient(top, #FFF4D5 0%, #bbbbbb 100%);  
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #efefef 0%, #bbbbbb 100%); 
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #FFF4D5 0%,#bbbbbb 100%); 
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 9px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
    padding: 0 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;  
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-table;

}
    nav ul:after {
        content: ""; clear: both; display: block;
    }

    nav ul li {
    float: left;
}

    nav ul li:hover {
        background: #66FFFF;
        background: linear-gradient(top, #663300 0%, #663300 40%);
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #663300 0%, #663300 40%);
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #663300 0%,#663300 40%);

    }
        nav ul li:hover a {
            color: #CC3300;

        }

    nav ul li a {
        display: block; padding: 25px 40px;
        color: #FFF4D5; text-decoration: none; z-index:-1;
    }

nav ul ul {
    background: #66FFFF; border-radius: 0px; padding: 0;
    position: absolute; top: 100%;
}
    nav ul ul li {
        float: none; 
        border-top: 1px solid #6b727c;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #575f6a;
        position: relative;

    }
        nav ul ul li a {
            padding: 15px 40px;
            color: #663300;

        }   
            nav ul ul li a:hover {
                background: #FFF4D5;
            }
    nav ul ul ul {
    position: absolute; left: 100%; top:0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to increase the [`z-index`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp) property for the menu CSS

Comment: Are you adding the z-index high enough in the menu tree? It should be on the node that is a sibling of the node wrapping the grid

Comment: @JDandChips you are correct i was placing the z-index at an lower level, i took that out and placed it where my <nav> is and it worked. thnx mate